How do I identify and correct a line continuation error in my Pinescript Script?
The problem is I am not a coder.  The script below is not processing due to incorrect syntax.  It is line continuation error.  The error occurs here:
** label.new(
x=index, **
you can test the code in Trading view.  It should allow one to count candles on the chart sequentially nothing fancy.
The full code is below:
//@version=5
indicator("Candle Labeler", overlay=true)

// Inputs
var label_start_index = input.int(1, title="Start Label From Candle Index", minval=1)
var int label_range = input.int(10, title="Number of Candles to Label", minval=1)
var color label_color = input.color(color.white, title="Label Color")
var int label_font_size = input.int(10, title="Font Size", minval=8, maxval=50)

// Function to create a label
labelCandle(index) =>
    label.new(
         x=index, 
         y=low[index], 
         text=tostring(index), 
         color=color.new(label_color, 0), 
         textcolor=label_color, 
         size=size.small, 
         style=label.style_label_down, 
         textalign=text.align_center, 
         text_size=label_font_size
    )

// Loop through candles and add labels
for i = label_start_index to (label_start_index + label_range - 1)
    labelCandle(i)

I tried correcting the syntax with chat GPT but it rendors the same code after I gave it the error indcator information from pinescript:
Mismatched input 'end of line without line continuation' expecting ')'
I also tried CodePal.ai and used the code fixer.

When you wrap lines, new lines should start with one or several (different f rom multiple of 4) spaces.
labelCandle(index) =>
    label.new(
         x=index, 
         y=low[index], 
         text=str.tostring(index), 
         color=color.new(label_color, 0), 
         textcolor=label_color, 
         size=size.small, 
         style=label.style_label_down, 
         textalign=text.align_center
     )

